# Navigation Component - Shared Element Transition not working at all

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, shared-element-transition

I'm using the latest Nav Component (2.2.0-alpha01) in my project, and am presented with an issue I can't seem to resolve.

I have a splash animation - nothing serious, a custom background stretching to the whole screen, and a logo in the very middle, using ConstraintLayout. During the initial sync, I animate a custom animated VectorDrawable (let's call it `@drawable/logo_animated`), which uses the common `@drawable/logo` as a source, and applies animations to its groups.

To time the animation right, I created the following helper function:

```
fun ImageView.setRepeatingAnimatedVector(
    @DrawableRes animationRes: Int,
    delayMs: Long = 0,
    startDelayMs: Long = 0,
    shouldRunOptional: () -> Boolean = { false },
    optionalRunnable: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    val anim = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(context, animationRes)?.apply {
        registerAnimationCallback(object : Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable?) {
                this@setRepeatingAnimatedVector.postDelayed({ if (shouldRunOptional()) optionalRunnable() else start() }, delayMs)
            }
        })
    }
    setImageDrawable(anim)
    postDelayed({ anim?.start() }, startDelayMs)
}
```

It takes an AnimatedVectorDrawable as an input, and applies it to the ImageView. Upon finishing the animation cycle, a check in the form of a lambda (`shouldRunOptional`) is ran. If it returns true, the `optionalRunnable` lambda is launched, otherwise it repeats the animation.

With this, I can wait for the ViewModel to finish syncing, and then await the end of the animation to move between fragments without any weirdness. The animation itself is short (~900ms), so at most the user will be delayed by a second.

I also use a custom NavigationManager composition for navigation. The Manager itself is an interface (`INavigationManager`) of generic calls (such as `splashToLanding()` or `openDetail(id: UUID)`) that gets injected into ViewModels, with an extra interface taking care of the NavComponent specific bits:

IFragmentNavigator.kt

```
interface IFragmentNavigator {
    val command: SingleLiveEvent<NavigationCommand>

    var splashLandingExtras: Navigator.Extras?

    fun setSplashLandingTransition(extras: Navigator.Extras) {
        splashLandingExtras = extras
    }

    fun back() {
        navigate(NavigationCommand.Back)
    }

    fun navigate(direction: NavDirections) {
        navigate(NavigationCommand.To(direction))
    }

    fun navigate(navCommand: NavigationCommand) {
        command.postValue(navCommand)
    }
}
```

The implementation just takes care of property initializations, and then later on used in the following manner:

```
class FragmentNavigationManager: 
    INavigationManager, IFragmentNavigator by FragmentNavigator() { [...] }
```

The `command` property of this interface is then later used in the Fragments, via Observers:

```
open val navigationObserver = Observer<NavigationCommand> {
        when(it) {
            is NavigationCommand.To -> findNavController().navigate(it.directions)
            is NavigationCommand.Back -> findNavController().popBackStack()
            is NavigationCommand.BackTo -> findNavController().popBackStack(it.destinationId, false)
            is NavigationCommand.ToRoot -> TODO()
        }
    }

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    navigator.command.observe(this, navigationObserver)
}
```

The `Directions` instance created in the FragmentNavigationManager is used by the NavController directly. I made sure to add the FragmentNavigator's Extras field to the actual navigation call:

```
    override fun splashToLanding() {
        navigate(
            NavigationCommand.To(
                SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToLandingFragment(),
                null, null, splashLandingExtras
            )
        )
    }
```

And of course in the SplashFragment, I assign the appropriate view to the transition name for `splashLandingExtras`:

```
navigator.splashLandingExtras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(binding.logo to "logo")
```

In the LandingFragment's `onCreate` method, I do set up enter and exit animations:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move).let {transition ->
            sharedElementEnterTransition = transition
            sharedElementReturnTransition = transition
        }
    }
```

The layouts are the following:

splash.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.felcana.app.viewmodel.SplashViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/background" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                style="?attr/logoStyle"
                android:transitionName="logo"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

landing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.my.app.viewmodel.LandingViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/background" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                style="?attr/logoStyle"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:transitionName="logo"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_register"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_register"
                style="?attr/flatWhiteButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToRegister()}"
                android:text="@string/button_register"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_login"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_login"
                style="?attr/borderlessWhiteButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="24dp"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToLogin()}"
                android:text="@string/button_login"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/disclaimer"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/disclaimer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/app_white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

For some reason, the animation does not play at all - the ImageView just jumps without any sort of transition to the new position.

What's going wrong here? According to the documentation, this should be working. I did try going back to more stable versions of the NavComponent library, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried postponing the enter transition inside `LandingFragment::onViewCreated` and manually setting the transition name to the view?

Something like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  // Pause the enter transition
  postponeEnterTransition()

  // Manually apply the transitionName
  logo.transitionName = "logo"

  // Resume the transition
  startPostponedEnterTransition()

  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
```